# r survey svyquantile: Rounding the number of decimal places

Tags: r, survey

```
library(haven)
library(survey)
library(dplyr)

nhanesDemo <- read_xpt(url("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT"))

# Rename variables into something more readable
nhanesDemo$fpl <- nhanesDemo$INDFMPIR
nhanesDemo$age <- nhanesDemo$RIDAGEYR
nhanesDemo$gender <- nhanesDemo$RIAGENDR
nhanesDemo$persWeight <- nhanesDemo$WTINT2YR
nhanesDemo$psu <- nhanesDemo$SDMVPSU
nhanesDemo$strata <- nhanesDemo$SDMVSTRA

# Select the necessary columns
nhanesAnalysis <- nhanesDemo %>%
  select(fpl, age, gender, persWeight, psu, strata)

# Set up the design
nhanesDesign <- svydesign(id      = ~psu,
                          strata  = ~strata,
                          weights = ~persWeight,
                          nest    = TRUE,
                          data    = nhanesAnalysis)

# Select those between the agest of 18 and 79
ageDesign <- subset(nhanesDesign, age > 17 & age < 80 & !is.na(fpl))

quantile_results <- svyquantile(~fpl, ageDesign, quantiles=c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9))
print(quantile_results)
```

The default rounding of `svyquantile` appears to be two digits past the decimal place. How can I change this? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.0/topics/svyquantile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svyquantile` does no rounding.

In this example, the two digit precision is the precision of the data: `fpl` is given to only two decimal places and by default `svyquantile` returns the left quantile, which is always one of the observed values. In fact, most of the distinct values of `fpl` occur multiple times: there are 20 observations equal to the 10th percentile, 29 equal to the median, and 1220 equal to the 90th percentile, so the quantile will be equal to one of the observed values in this example no matter what you specify for the `qrule` argument.

If you make `fpl` noisier, you'll get more digits

```
> ageDesign<-update(ageDesign, fpl_noisy=fpl+runif(nrow(ageDesign),0,0.005))
> svyquantile(~fpl_noisy, ageDesign, quantiles=c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9))
$fpl_noisy
     quantile    ci.2.5   ci.97.5         se
0.1 0.8027744 0.7128426 0.8841695 0.04019022
0.5 2.9711470 2.5921659 3.3747105 0.18357099
0.9 5.0031355 5.0027002 5.0035307 0.00019482

attr(,"hasci")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"class")
[1] "newsvyquantile"
```